# How to get the last time a file was modified in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to get the last time the date a file was modified. I used a variable for date and a variable for time.

This will get the date and time but I want to use `-r` using the `date` command to make a reflection of when the date was last modified. Just not sure how I go about using it in my variables.

How would I go about doing this?

Here are my variables:

```
DATE="$(date  +'%m/%d/%Y')"
TIME="$(date  +'%H:%M')"
```

I tried putting the `-r` after and before the time and date.

Comment: What do those variables have to do with file modification times? They're just the current date and time.

Comment: Well i am using this script to output to a .php file using a cron scheduler. The cron scheduler executes the script which will update the .php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though people might tell you, you should *not* parse the output of `ls`, simply that can easily break if your file name contains tabs, spaces, line breaks, your user decides to simply specify a different set of `ls` options, the `ls` version you find is not behaving like you expected...

Use `stat` instead:

```
stat -c '%Y'
```

will give you the seconds since `epoch`.

Try

```
date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' $myfile)" "+%m/%d/%Y"
```

to get the date, and read through `man date` to get the time in the format you want to, replacing '%F' in the command line above:

```
date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' $myfile)" "+%H:%M"
```

EDIT: used your formats.

EDIT2: I really don't think your date format is wise, because it's just so ambiguous for anyone not from the US, and also it's not easily sortable. But it's a cultural thing, so this is more of a hint: If you want to make your usable for people from abroad, either use Year-month-day as format, or get the current locale's setting to format dates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
ls -lt myfile.txt
```

Here in 6th column you will see when file was modified.

Or you could use `stat myfile.txt` to check the modified time of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GNU `stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

```sh
mtime=$(stat --format=%y filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a *very* old question, but, for the sake of completeness, I'm including an additional answer here.

The original question does *not* specify the specific operating system. `stat` differs significantly from SysV-inspired Unixes (e.g. Linux) and BSD-inspired ones (e.g. Free/Open/NetBSD, macOS/Darwin).

Under macOS Big Sur (11.5), you can get the date of a file with a single `stat` command:

```sh
stat -t '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' -f "%Sm" myfile.txt
```

will output

```
04/10/2021 23:22
```

for April 10, 2021.

You can easily put that in two commands, one for the date, another for the time, of course, to comply with the original question as formulated.